# :before selector not adding content

Tags: html, css, backbone.js, handlebars.js, pseudo-element

I'm trying to add an image before other images.  It should be before every image except the first one.  So thought of adding it like:

```
.class3:not(:first-child):before {
  background-image: url('image.jpg');
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}
```

The html gets added dynamically through Backbone and uses Handlebars.  It looks something like this:

```
<div class="class1">
  <div class="class2">
    {{#each item}}
      <div class="class3" style="background-image: url('{{image1}}')">
        <p>{{text}}</p>
        <img class="dialog-popup-rewards" src={{image2}} />
      </div>
    {{/each}}
 </div>
</div>
```

But nothing gets added.  I tested the before statement with less complexity.  Adding a before to all of the divs:

```
.class3:before {
    background-color: black;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```

And it never gets added.  What am I missing?  I rewrote the code for the sake of clarity, so I might have slipped in some syntax errors.

Would it be better to try this with a Handlebars helper?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Very likely it is because you don't have any `content` defined. Could you try setting the image to the `content` property (instead of `background-image`) and also use `first-child` instead of `firstchild`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to include a content property in your :before css block.  It can be just an empty string.  Try this for your simplified example:

```
.class3:before {
    content: '';
    background-color: black;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
}
```